# (spoilers) Help! My group was playing risk legacy and the contents of the two pockets were swapped at the factory, help please!

Tags: risk-legacy

Alright, basically, what happened is that on the second game we were able to open the pocket which says "open when a player is about to place 30+ troops on the board while they have a missle in their hand" (spoilers incoming). When we opened it, we were very confused. None of it made any sense really as the first thing we saw was the mutant faction. We got all the event cards for the mutants and bringer of nuclear fire, all the troops and everything and we were weirded out as none of it made any sense at all. We played the game normally and Sahara won.

Well we just finished game 3 and didn't open any packets or pockets that game. Afterwards, I looked for a complete list of spoilers and when I found it I saw what the 30+ troops pocket was supposed to be: Aliens. Now I checked, and we didn't break any rules. We opened the right pocket on game two, it just had the wrong stuff on it. "Open when using three missles in one combat roll" was still closed. Me and my brother decided to open it to see whether we got two mutant factions or swapped mutants and aliens. Either would've been a problem and I don't have a solution for either. What we have now is two swapped pockets. On game 2 we should have got aliens, but we have mutants, and we also already placed 3 missle powers on Die Mechaniker, Imperial Balkania and the Saharan republic. So far, the solution me and my brother have come up with is to place mutants and all their respective event cards (including the two remaining missle powers) back in the pocket they're supposed to be in, and re-open it when we actually meet it's requirements, until then we will ignore all missle powers already placed on factions.

Die mechaniker was supposed to be the alien collaborator and place his 30 troops on the alien island, but we never got around to that for the obvious reason that the contents of both pockets were swapped and we didn't catch it until after game 3. So far we haven't used any of the missle powers, but we still have the problem that one of the players in our group is hoping to gain "the bringer of nuclear fire" token next game and place the fallout territory. One of the ideas I had was to have the player who completed the objective game 2 to place the alien island at the start of game 4 and place 30 alien troops on that island with their HQ with the stipulation that nobody could play as the aliens in the fourth game. My brother disagreed. There is also the idea to just help him "re-open" the 30+ troops packet (even though the thing is already torn off) and just have it play normally, but I still don't know what to do to fix this.

Comment: We had the same issue, seems to be a common factory error?

Comment: Seems to be a common error: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1451620/misslabled-packets-anyone-else-have-spoiler-free